# Showing generic error pages to users in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and I'm wondering if Yii has anything built in to handle generic error pages to show to users.

Like for example you may want to show them a general error page because their logout failed for some reason or a range of other reasons. Stuff that you don't want to have to create a view for every situation.

Is there something like this available and if so, how do you use it?

Comment: What specifically are you interested in? Check out this section of official documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for - isn't that more for unencountered for errors? Like server errors? Not errors you  code for and want to display custom error messages to your users.

Comment: You can throw the exception when it's needed (for example logout failed) and site/error view will be rendered by default. Customization described in this section: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html#using-error-actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the basic and the advance apps come with it by default:

```
'components' => [
..................
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
..............

class SiteController extends Controller
............
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
```

You just have to throw an error now and you will see the page.

Comment: Thanks. So what does the reference to `yii\web\ErrorAction` do? Do you need to include this method in each model for it to work?

Comment: No, first this is a controller not a model and you do not have to put it in every controller, why would u want to have error handling in every controller? You want to have 1 place for it.

Comment: Ahh sorry, meant controller.

Comment: Anyone know how a Page Title is passed to the errorAction?

Comment: It is not, why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

make sure YII_DEBUG is false.
if YII_DEBUG is true then error stack is displayed.
You can define YII_DEBUG By

1) index.php

```
//remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
//specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
```

OR

2).envFramework

```
YII_DEBUG   = true
YII_ENV     = dev
```